# What would the perihelion of Ulysses's orbit have been without a trajectory adjustment after its Jupiter swingby?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, probe, gravity-assist, ulysses

I'm wondering what the perihelion of the orbit of Ulysses spacecraft would have been had a trajectory adjustment after its Jupiter swingby not taken place? On Wikipedia it says "The size and shape of the orbit were adjusted to a much smaller degree so that aphelion remained at approximately 5 AU, Jupiter's distance from the Sun, and perihelion was somewhat greater than 1 AU, the Earth's distance from the Sun.", and I've tried to find more elaborate information on this trajectory adjustment, but haven't been able to dig anything up.

I'm asking because I'm running a simulation of Ulysses's trajectory, but it does not take the trajectory adjustment mentioned above into account, and the orbit you end up with has an aphelion at about 5 astronomical units, but the perihelion is well within the orbit of Mercury. So what I'm curious about is whether that would have been Ulysses's trajectory without the post Jupiter swingby burn.

Comment: My apologies fellow community members, but the burn in question was conducted on the 8'th of July 1991 before the Jupiter swingby, and not afterwards. This wasn't altogether clear in the wikipedia article. However, factoring in this burn, I get the correct orbit where the perihelion of Ulysses is just outside of Earth's orbit.

Comment: Ah, here's a link for that: https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?feature=5674 "The 81/2-minute maneuver began at 6:24 a.m. Pacific Daylight Time. NASA and European Space Agency officials said the maneuver was minor and was designed to alter the spacecraft's trajectory by about 0.29 meters per second (less than one foot per second). "

Comment: Indeed @uhoh! Feel free to turn that into an answer; for whatever reason I'm not entirely comfortable with the idea of answering my own questions, even though I realize that it could be of benefit to the wider community as a quality answer is a quality answer regardless of who did the answering, haha. If anybody is curious about the simulation, feel free to hit me up in the chat and I'll send a link to it once I'm back from work!

Comment: Hey, yea, I didn't get a notification, no clue why, but here's a link to the simulator: https://thehappykoala.github.io/Gravity-Playground/ It's still a rather buggy affair and very much a work in progress, but feel free to check it out and if you have time provide feedback :)!

Comment: And if you click on the credits you'll see that you're mentioned there; an answer you provided a while ago helped me implement the rotating reference frame feature. Let me know if you don't want to be listed, but I like giving credit when it's due!

Comment: Oh, I take it you're a connoisseur of Python, then. I'll remove you from the list of credits as soon as I'm back home from work. My apologies for any inconvenience caused. You'll find the integrator code here: https://github.com/TheHappyKoala/Gravity-Playground/blob/master/src/js/Physics/index.js. It's nothing fancy. This is quickly veering off into off topic territory, though, so I'll stop here and thank you for your insights.

Comment: I've cleaned up some comments. I love to chat about orbital mechanics. You can start a question-specific chat room here, or just go to the main chat room. A dedicated room is better because it might take several cycles because of time zones. Maybe you can add a better integration method for accuracy and speed? random example: http://static.mtdevans.com/2013/05/fourth-order-runge-kutta-algorithm-in-javascript-with-demo/ if you can't find a library

Comment: That sounds great. Not quite sure how I can create a question specific chat room, though... I'm a n00b in the true sense of the word when it comes to Stack Exchange. As you point out, the integrator could be improved on massively, and what I'd like from my integrator is that it conserves energy while allowing for a variable time step. Is that a case of wanting to both keep and eat the cake? My concern about RK integrators is that they don't conserve energy. On the other hand, leapfrog and verlet schemes require fixed time steps, which makes simulating spacecraft missions kind of tricky.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83502/discussion-between-uhoh-and-happy-koala).

Comment: There it is, TCM-3A on July 8 https://web.archive.org/web/20070720104455/http://ulysses-ops.jpl.esa.int/ulsfct/opssumm.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments above, the trajectory adjustment took place on the eighth of July 1991, before Ulysses swung by Jupiter. For more information on its trajectory, please consult:

http://adsbit.harvard.edu//full/1992A%26AS...92..207W/0000209.000.html

By changing the start date of the simulation to the first of August 1991, half a year before the Jupiter gravity assist, I was able to simulate the actual orbit of Ulysses. In the image of my simulation below, you will see that Ulysses starts out in an orbit that follows the ecliptic, but once it encounters Jupiter in February 1992, it gets deflected out of the ecliptic into an orbit, which brings it over both the North and South poles of the Sun, with a periohelion just outside Earth's orbit and an aphelion of about five astronomical units.

[image]